# Overfitting/Underfitting Machine Learning Models with Azure Machine Learning vs Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm learning how to perform Machine Learning with Azure ML Studio. At the moment, I've only played around with Machine Learning using Python.

I have run identical Machine Learning projects using both Azure ML and Python to see how close the results of each product with the Root Mean Squared Errors (RMSE). So far the RMSE has been widely different for Azure ML and Python.

I can't figure out why the RMSE is so far apart. The only reason I can think of is because of the way Python 'fits' the model on the training data. Python uses the following code to fit the training data

```
lr = LinearRegression(labelCol='xxxx')
lrModel = lr.fit(train_data)
```

However, I don't know how Azure ML fits the training data.

Can someone let me know how Azure ML accomplishes fitting the training data?

Comment: Perhaps also the RMSE is calculated differently in Azure..

Comment: @LucAs, thanks for getting in touch. That is exactly what I'm hoping someone will be able to tell me, and how Azure go about fitting the data to the training model?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how Azure goes about fitting the model, but I posted an idea for you that Azure might calculate the RSE instead of the RMSE

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you probably used RMSE = √( 1/n ∑ (y_i - pred_i)^2 ) to calculate the RMSE in python, where y are the true labels, pred are the predicted ones in the linear regression?

I can imagine Azure using a slightly different term, namely RSE = √( 1/(n-2) ∑ (y_i - pred_i)^2 ), in which the Bessel's Correcting term 1/(n-2) is used instead. This is used to correct for the bias of fitting 2 parameters (assuming the linear regression is only fitting the slope and the intercept, otherwise 1/(n-k) is the Bessel's Correction when fitting k parameters in a multivariate linear regression)

Try it out! I cannot explain however why the difference between python and Azure is so large, since the Bessel's Correcting term should only make a small difference.

Comment: @Luz As, the python used to for the project can be found here https://github.com/SuperJohn/spark-and-python-for-big-data-with-pyspark/blob/master/Spark_for_Machine_Learning/Linear_Regression/Linear_Regression_Consulting_Project_SOLUTIONS.ipynb    I used the same project with Azure ML. With the python method I got an RMSE of 0.890179, whereas with Azure ML I got an RMSE of 2.09. The only thing I can think of why they're so far apart is because of the differences in the way they fit the training data to the model, but not sure

Comment: Hard to say.. Im guessing its not that Azure fits the model differently, Im guessing a typo or error somewhere?